# MapKit's hybrid map type hides country names

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm using mapkit's **hybrid** type, I want to show city names and hide country names.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the details of maps like this with MapKit. I would recommend instead something like the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) if you want stylistic control of the map.